# sendgrid max size of message sent at the time

Tags: php, sendgrid, kohana-3

We have used sendgrid for sending email in Kohana 3.2 (PHP 5.5). We have select more user and send the mail means some of the user is not recived the mail.    It is not working more than 300 user means only. But it is work below the  200 user means .

Answer (score 4):

The total message size is limited to 20,480,000 bytes, or approximately 19.5MB. This includes all the headers, body, and attachments. From the [SendGrid Attachment Docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Build/Add_Content/attachments.html#-Limitations)

Comment: in version 3 the Total (Message) Size was increased to 30MB:. [Limitations](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/limitations)

For some set of "high volume" users they can accept the data gziped which allows larger raw data. [v3 Mail Send - Mail Body Compression](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send#mail-body-compression).